# after user authenticates FB app, how can you get all likes from a specific domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website called example.com with several internal pages that are liked.

I created a FB app.

when a user authenticates the FB app, I want to fetch ALL user likes such as: example.com/page1, example.com/page2, etc.

(a single user can have up to 100+ likes on the internal pages of example.com) I essentially want to get all the liked URL's (and associated FB graph ID) the authenticated user has made on my example.com website.

is there a way to do this?

perhaps via a facebook.api call? or perhaps a FQL query? I am open to PHP or JS.

please help! thanks.

...fyi, My initial thought is to for each user, fetch ALL their likes, parse through each one to make sure it came from example.com, and then store those like URL's into a local database. when the user re-visits the site, I will query my database for likes associated with that user. this did not seem the most efficient as it would require storing all likes ever made on my website. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to store when a user likes a page on your website why not make use of the `edge.create` and `edge.remove` events the Facebook JS SDK provides? Example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl, elm) {
    // Make a request to server to save 'Like' information
});

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(targetUrl, elm) {
    // Make a request to server to remove 'Like' information
});
```

Comment: thanks Nav. this would work, except, the action of 'liking' occurs on a different domain that I do not have access to. I do however have access to example.com where I plan to fetch all the 'likes' of the other domain. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I see in the attributes of the like plugin, that the ref attribute might be what you could use to determine where a like came from.  Of course your href attribute would need to be the same on all locations of the like button.

Or, you can register your site with facebook insights and track it there.  See https://www.facebook.com/insights/

Answer (score 0):

The User API reference is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Here's how you get all the likes via the JS API (unless they're more than one page, they you get a subset of the likes):

```
FB.api('/me/likes', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

You need to be logged in, and you need the user_likes permission.